# Prove for a close subset of $\mathbb R$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

> Let $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid 0\leq x\}$. Prove that $S$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I know I need to show that $\forall x \exists x_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} x\in S$, but I have no idea as to how.

Comment: My apologies for the wrong answer. Please accept others' correct answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer is incorrect.  To show that $S$ is closed, you must show that for *any* sequence of points $(x_n)$ in $S$ which converges to a limit $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the limit $x$ is also in $S$.  You can prove this for your $S$ by contradiction: suppose $x_n\to x$ but $x\not\in S$.  Now use the definition of limit (with $\epsilon=-x$) to show that actually not every $x_n$ is in $S$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $y \not \in S; (y \in \mathbb R)$.  Then $y < 0$.

Can you show that $y$ is not a limit point of $S$?

Let $\{x_n\} \subset S$ be *any* sequence.  Then all $x_i \ge 0 >y$ so $|y - x_i| = x_i - y = x_i + |y| \ge |y|$.  So for any $0 < \epsilon < |y|$ then $|y-x_i|  \ge \epsilon$ for all $x_i$.  So $x_n \not \rightarrow y$.

So $y$ can not be a limit point. So all points not in $S$ are not limit points.  So the only points that are limit points must be in $S$.  So $S$ is closed.

====

Another but maybe more direct but not as clear way would be: Let $x_n \rightarrow x$ and all $x_i \le 0$.  Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $x_j$ such that $x - \epsilon < x_j < x+ \epsilon$.  So $x < x_j + \epsilon < 0 + \epsilon$.  So $x < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$.  No positive number is smaller than all positive numbers (including itself!) so $x \le 0$.  So $x \in S$.

Comment: If I am not wrong $y\notin S\implies y<0$

Comment: Oops you are right.  I had flipped S to be -S = [0,inf).  Same argument.  I'll fix.